# zend framework multiple input file upload

Tags: file, zend-framework, input, element

i have a form that contains two file element with unique name. i want to reach each file element from Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http(); how can i do that?
if i use

```
$apt = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
.
.
$apt->receive();
```

two files have been uploaded. but i execute different queries for each file element.

for example

```
$smallPic = small pic name that i get from input smallPic
i execute 
update products set smallPic = '$smallPic'
and for large pic
$largePic = large pic name that i get from input largePic
i execute 
update products set largePic = '$largePic'
```

how can i reach each input file element with $apt ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code I have used in the past to receive multiple files from a `Zend_Form` where many of the file upload fields were dynamic and not part of the form.

Since you know the names of the two file uploads, you can also say `$apt->getFileInfo('my_file');`

```
$apt    = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$files  = $apt->getFileInfo();

foreach($files as $file => $fileInfo) {
    if ($apt->isUploaded($file)) {
        if ($apt->isValid($file)) {
            if ($apt->receive($file)) {
                $info = $apt->getFileInfo($file);
                $tmp  = $info[$file]['tmp_name'];
                $data = file_get_contents($tmp);
                // here $tmp is the location of the uploaded file on the server
                // var_dump($info); to see all the fields you can use
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: doh! how can i forget getFileInfo() method. thanks for reply, foreach loop doesn't helpful, but i can reach element with $file = $apt->getFileInfo('smallPic');

and last question
i think all file elements handled with one zend file adapter. is there any way to create another adapter ? or is it a good practice ?

Comment: It is okay to use the one adapter, if you are using `Zend_Form` to create your form, then you don't have to use `Zend_File_Transfer` manually since `Zend_Form` can take care of most of the work.  See [Zend_Form_Element_File](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file)

Comment: I wish the documentation included a simple multi-file example like this.

Comment: @chrishiestand, yeah it's been long time, do you still need it ?

Comment: @hrnsky thanks, but I think I just used your example (because I +1'd your answer). At this point, I don't quite recall what I used it for.